# Trying to pass a redux action as prop to a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a Parent component "Header" which holds a child component "LogoutButton",

code: Header:

```
import LogoutButton from "./HeaderComps/LogoutButton";
import { setIsLoggedIn } from "../redux/action";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Header extends Component {
handleLogOut() {
const { setIsLoggedIn } = this.props;
   setIsLoggedIn(x,y,z)
  }


render() {
    return (
      <LogoutButton click={this.handleLogOut}/>
    );
  }


}


export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
    isAdmin: state.isAdmin,
    userName: state.userName
  }),
  { setIsLoggedIn }
)(Header);
```

LogoutButton:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { setIsLoggedIn } from "../../redux/action";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function LogoutButton(props) {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-warning"
      id="LogoutButton"
      onClick={props.click}
    >
      Log out
    </button>
  );
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
    isAdmin: state.isAdmin,
    userName: state.userName
  }),
  { setIsLoggedIn }
)(LogoutButton);
```

As you can see **setIsLoggedIn()** is an action from redux, which works.
What I'm trying to do is make it work when clicking on **LogoutButton**.
I tried to pass it as a prop but it doesn't effect anything...
Is there a way to pass a redux action as a prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few issues:

1. your action setIsLoggedIn and callback props are with the same name.
2. you need to use arrow function for access to this, other option is to bind the this context on constructor
3. you don't need to connect your Header component

```
import LogoutButton from "./HeaderComps/LogoutButton";

class Header extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <LogoutButton />
    );
  }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { setIsLoggedIn as setIsLoggedInAction  } from "../../redux/action";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function LogoutButton(props) {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-warning"
      id="LogoutButton"
      onClick={props.setIsLoggedIn}
    >
      Log out
    </button>
  );
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
    isAdmin: state.isAdmin,
    userName: state.userName
  }),
  { setIsLoggedIn: setIsLoggedInAction }
)(LogoutButton);
```

Comment: That Worked  thanks alot. By the way I do have to connect the Header component because there is much more code inside that  I did not show...

Comment: so you can replace props.click with your connected setIsLoggedIn action on Header component